# Can I use a gutted sub panel as a junction box

Tags: junction-box

I am going to be replacing my all in one 100A breaker panel with a 200A panel. The old panel has the ground/neutral bus at the bottom of the box and the wires are cut too short to reach the bus bars on the new box. The hot wires may also pose a challenge as well. I have been looking for recessed J boxes but find it impossible to find online. So I was thinking of getting a indoor recessed breaker panel and gutting it and using it for a J box. Does anyone know if this will pass inspection?

I know I can use connectors in the main panel, but I prefer to do a cleaner job in the breaker box.

Comment: How big of a box are you after?

Comment: I gather location of the neutral bus was not a consideration when you purchased the box?  It's one of those details the big box store staff will not mention... ThreePhaseEel knows boxes and will likely be able to recommend one that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: I've used old fuse panel boxes for simple nut junction housings when moving a panel. Inspector was fine with it. I'm not sure if you intend to use the bus bars for your situation. That could change things. I think fill rules are your primary hurdle.

Comment: Harper, I have done a lot of research on these all in one panels. Between the power company and my association, it limits me severely. There is nothing on the market that I can find that has the ground/neutral close enough.

Answer (score 1):

### You don't need to do that -- you can get a flush-mount box by itself that fits your needs

What you're looking for isn't a "breaker panel", really.  It's just the *cabinet* that the breaker panel came in, so just get a suitable box instead.  The term you are after is "flush mount NEMA 1 enclosure", and it will look something like [this](https://www.kele.com/product/sku?kid=AFE1084B) (illustration and link for exposition only):

[image: Hoffman AFE series flush mount NEMA 1 enclosure]

Comment: Wow, thanks. this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm upgrading the panel from 100 to 200A and this might work. I need to figure if I can fit 19 circuits in it. I will look up the NEMA 1 as that is what I was missing when I was looking up flush mount enclosures. Thanks